# Google+ Auto Backup vs Instant Upload

Tags: google-plus, instant-upload

What is the difference in Auto Backup and Instant Upload?

Comment: According to this article, it just looks like a rebranding. http://www.nbcnews.com/technology/google-gains-41-new-features-auto-awesome-photos-hangouts-redesign-1C9929355

Comment: You have unlimited storage if you set G+ to resize your photos to 2048px. If you set it to keep the original image size AND the original image has any one side greater than 2048px (I think 4 megapixels is 2048x2048px) then it counts against your 5gb (or 15gb or whatever it is) free limit.

Comment: That's pretty good to know @Ian! Do you have any reference for that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same thing, auto backup is basically just a new (and more appropriate) name. The only thing that changed is that now it uploads your pictures in original quality (part of the reason why they bumped up everyone's google drive limit to 15GB)

Comment: Instant Upload was unlimited storage. Does Auto Backup count against the drive space?